# concurrent modification exception happens at an expected time

Tags: java, multithreading, iterator

There is a list which is being sorted and iterated by two threads at the same time. As expected, it leads to `ConcurrentModificationException`. What is unclear is the timing of the error.

```java
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Confusionist {
    static List<Integer> numbers;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      numbers = IntStream.generate(() -> java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt()).limit(100).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
      new Thread(new Accessor()).start();
      new Thread(new Accessor()).start();
    }
    
    static class Accessor implements Runnable{
        public void run(){
            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            char threadDenoter = threadName.charAt(threadName.length()-1);
            System.out.printf("Thread: %s, Going to sort\n", threadName);
            Collections.sort(numbers, Integer::compareTo);
            Iterator<Integer> iterator = numbers.iterator();
            System.out.printf("Thread: %s, Going to iterate\n", threadName);
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                iterator.next();
                System.out.printf("%c", threadDenoter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output: (Which occurs few times)

```
Thread: Thread-0, Going to sort
Thread: Thread-1, Going to sort
Thread: Thread-0, Going to iterate
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1013)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:967)
    at HelloCodiva$Accessor.run(HelloCodiva.java:21)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
000000Thread: Thread-1, Going to iterate
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
Completed with exit code: 0
```

Both the threads have sorted the same list, they have acquired an iterator and they have started with the iteration. (prints 0 and 1).

When one of the threads completes the iteration (here thread 1 completes iteration has it has printed 100 1's), the other iteration fails.

1. Why is the other thread's iteration fail when the first thread completes?
2. When both the threads have completed sorting and acquired iterator's respectively, the underlying iterators are not going to change. Why does this leads to exception at this stage?

Answer (score 0):

> When both the threads have completed sorting and acquired iterator's respectively, the underlying iterators are not going to change. Why does this leads to exception at this stage?

This assumption that since list is already sorted and second sort will not invalidate the iterator is not true. If thread-1 sort the list after thread-0 has initialized the iterator, iterator acquired by thread-0 will be become invalid and throw ConcurrentModificationException when accessed.

I can think of one sequence of operation to explain messages/errors. Assume thread-0 sorted the list, created a iterator and printed say 80 odd numbers and then context switch happened. Thread-1 will resort the array and print 100 times. Now when thread-0 gets rescheduled its iterator will no longer be valid and will throw exception.

To test it myself I wrote this simple code and it throws ConcurrentModificationException.

```
List<Integer> list =
        IntStream.generate(() -> java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(10))
            .limit(10)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.sort(list, Integer::compareTo);
    Iterator<Integer> itr = list.iterator();
    Collections.sort(list, Integer::compareTo);

    while (itr.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println(itr.next());
    }
```

Interesting part is this is only true for type of list Collectors.toList() return. I dont see same behavior if just use ArrayList.